# Error when trying to check if email already exists in db

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am receiving this error when I try to check if an email already exists in the database and not sure why:

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ""

Here is my code:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
//prepare and set the query and then execute it
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();

// grab the result
$stmt->store_result();

// get the count
$numRows = $stmt->num_rows();

if( $numRows )
{

echo "<p class='red'>Email is already registered with us</p>";
}
else


//if we have no errors, do the SQL
```

I have a seperate database connection file:

```
function DB2($host='', $user='', $password='', $db='') {

     /* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
     $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

     if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit();
     }    

     return $mysqli;
  }
```

Which is linked to this file using:

```
$conn2 = DB2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what language this is in. I'm assuming it's perl and dbi.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
//prepare and set the query and then execute it
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param($email);
$stmt->execute();
```

should be

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
//prepare and set the query and then execute it
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = ? fetch first row only");
$stmt->execute($email);
```

I don't know what store_result() is. I don't think it's part of DBI. You possibly want to do:

```
@found = $stmt->selectrow_array();
if ($#found) { #email was found }
```